# Why does my program skip a switch instruction?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program, where after 7 **floats** inputted by the user; they get stored into an array, then get printed out like this:

`DAY    VALUE    ISTOGRAM
   1     37.8    ***
   2     40.6    ******`

where the number of `*` in the Istogram column is given by `value - 34`.

I've written this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define OBSERVATION 7
#define MEDIAN 34

int main() {
  float temp[OBSERVATION] = {0};

  printf("Insert the patient's temperature over the course of 7 days: ");
  for(int i = 1; i <= OBSERVATION; i++){
    scanf("%f", &temp[i]);
  }

  printf("DAY\tVALUE\tISTOGRAM\n");
  for(int i = 1; i <= OBSERVATION; i++){
    printf("%6d\t%6g\n", i, temp[i]);
  }
  for(int i = 1; i <= OBSERVATION; i++){
    switch ((int)temp[i] - MEDIAN) {
      case 0: break;
      case 1: printf("\t\t\t\t*");
              break;
      case 2: printf("\t\t\t\t**");
              break;
      case 3: printf("\t\t\t\t***");
              break;
      case 4: printf("\t\t\t\t****");
              break;
      case 5: printf("\t\t\t\t*****");
              break;
      case 6: printf("\t\t\t\t******");
              break;
      case 7: printf("\t\t\t\t*******");
              break;
      case 8: printf("\t\t\t\t********");
              break;
      case 9: printf("\t\t\t\t*********");
              break;
      case 10: printf("\t\t\t\t*********");
               break;
      case 11: printf("\t\t\t\t**********");
               break;
      case 12: printf("\t\t\t\t***********");
               break;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The code compiles fine and outputs the first two columns correctly, but completely skips the `switch` statement. I've already tried to check if it erroneously assigns `0` to `temp[i]` when it gets cast to an **int**, but it doesn't do that. It simply skips the `switch`.

Also do you have a more "compact" way on how to print out the `*` column without using a `switch`?

Comment: In c, when indexing arrays, what do indexes start at? So how many elements does `temp` have, from what index to what index?

Comment: Even ignoring the issue with 1-7 vs 0-6 for the indexing, your code outputs (attempts to output) 7 pairs of day/temperature on 7 lines, and then outputs lots of tabs and stars on the next line — because that's how you've written the code.  You need the `switch()` inside the first loop, and you need to lose the `\n` from the first printf and add one after the strings of stars.  That would at least get you more or less what you're expecting.  That switch statement should probably be replaced with a loop (or call to a function containing a loop) to print the appropriate number of stars.

Comment: And what is the possible range of values input as temperatures for each day? Could they, possibly, be lower than MEDIAN? Or greater than MEDIAN+12?

Comment: As for the "compact" for your stars: you can be creative and write the cases in reverse order, starting with `case 12`. Make every case print just one asterisk and omit the `break`s – there. Me, I would simply write a loop.

Comment: did you try replacing the `temp[I]` with `temp[i]`?

Comment: And I would use round () function with abs() function if I'll use signed integers.

Comment: @barny I know that arrays start from 0, but it doesn't really matter in this case cause temp[0] is automatically equal to 0 and it never gets used later on, so it doesn't create any issues. In fact, the output for the days and value column is 100% correct

Comment: @JonathanLeffler oh yea you're right on the second part. I tried writing a loop too at the beginning but couldn't get it to work properly so I opted for an easier switch ahah

Comment: @barny no, they can't be any lower than median nor higher than median+12

Comment: @TahaPaksu I don't know why it wrote it like that here, in the original code is temp[i]. Besides, if it was temp[I] it would give me an error.

Comment: @usr2564301 any suggestions on that for loop? thanks ahah

Comment: You may be equating “can’t be” with “won’t be” - so you should make you code handle those unpredictable occasions when you enter 33, or 47.

Comment: So if you “know” indexes start with 0, how many elements does `temp` contain, and (because c indexes are based at 0) what is the valid range of index for `temp`?

Comment: @barny temp has 7 element from 0 to 6......

Comment: Yes, and you are accessing 1 to 7. Going out of the valid range of index value results in undefined behaviour. It might work. It might work one day but not the next. It might work with one compiler but not another. It might not work. It might ... etc. So getting the index variables in range is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite your code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "math.h"
#define OBSERVATION 7
#define MEDIAN 34

int main() {
  float temp[OBSERVATION] = {0};
  int iDifference = 0;

  printf("Insert the patient's temperature over the course of 7 days: \n");
  for(int i = 0; i < OBSERVATION; i++){
    scanf("%f", &temp[i]);
  }
```

then print the headers:

```
  printf("DAY\tVALUE\tISTOGRAM\n");
```

start the row loop:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < OBSERVATION; i++){
    // calculate the difference integer
    iDifference = round(temp[i] - MEDIAN);
    // don't add stars if the temperature diff is lower than 0
    if(iDifference < 0) iDifference = 0;
    // print the first two columns, notice that the new line isn't added yet
    printf("%6d\t%6.2f\t", i, temp[i]);
    // print the stars
    vDrawStars(iDifference);
    // then write the newline character
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

then the drawing stars routine:

```
void vDrawStars(int prm_iCount){
    int p = 0;
    // I didn't understand the case for it but
    // printf("\t\t\t\t");
    // then draw the needed stars
    for(p = 0; p < prm_iCount; p++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    // no new lines, still on the same line.
}
```

Here's a demo here: https://onlinegdb.com/BJPyvDJRX

Comment: Still `for(int i = 1; i <= OBSERVATION; i++){
    scanf("%f", &temp[i]);` accesses temp out of bounds.

Comment: Fail on the indexing into `temp`

Comment: Yep I've missed that. Fixed.

Comment: Wow thanks dude, really appreciate the time you put into this. I had tried to write a for loop like that at the beginning and I think it was pretty much the same, but it didn't work out, don't really know why. Again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works incorrectly, because you access the array `temp` out of bounds. Array indexes start with zero, so you should index with `for(int i = 0; i < OBSERVATION; i++)`.

The switch:

```
switch ((int)temp[i] - MEDIAN) {
      case 0: break;
      case 1: printf("\t\t\t\t*");
              break;
      case 2: printf("\t\t\t\t**");
              break;
      case 3: printf("\t\t\t\t***");
              break;
      case 4: printf("\t\t\t\t****");
              break;
      case 5: printf("\t\t\t\t*****");
              break;
      case 6: printf("\t\t\t\t******");
              break;
      case 7: printf("\t\t\t\t*******");
              break;
      case 8: printf("\t\t\t\t********");
              break;
      case 9: printf("\t\t\t\t*********");
              break;
      case 10: printf("\t\t\t\t*********");
               break;
      case 11: printf("\t\t\t\t**********");
               break;
      case 12: printf("\t\t\t\t***********");
               break;
    }
```

may be optimized just to:

```
    const int val = (int)temp[i] - MEDIAN;
    if (1 <= val && val <= 12) {   // make sure it's between 1 and 12
        printf("\t\t\t\t%.*s", val, "***********");
    }
```

1. The printf format modifier `"%.*s"` takes two parameters - length of the string to print and the string itself
2. We print `val` length of `"**********"` characters.